# Order by relationship with pagination laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the relationship below, an application belongs to a user.

**Users table**

```
ID | Name
 1 | Danny
 2 | Mark
```

**Applications table**

```
ID | user_id
 1 | 1
 2 | 2
```

**Application.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I'm trying to sort the application by user's name  and paginate the result. I tried the code below, the pagination is working but the order by doesn't have any effect.

```
    $query = Application::query();

    $query = $query->with(['user' => function ($query){
            $query->orderBy('name', 'DESC');
    }]);

    $query = $query->paginate(10);
```

Comment: have any solution with the `with()`and `paginate()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using inner join and order by relation column:

```php
$applications = Application::select('*')
    ->join('authors', 'applications.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->orderBy('authors.name', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: and without the join?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
Application::join('users', 'applications.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->orderBy('users.name','desc')
    ->with('users')
    ->get();
```

Comment: and without the join?